# Snowflake -When value doesn't exist make sure its NULL and not empty

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following `fb.org_story`  that returns some rows empty, I want to  change that so instead of empty it shows NULL (without creating a file format)

```
select 
fb.org_story as pvt_story
from prod.facebook fb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NULLIF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nullif.html) is a little short than use a full IFF or CASE statement

```
SELECT
    NULLIF(fb.org_story,'') AS pvt_story
FROM prod.facebook AS fb
```

But if the string has whitespace around it you might need to [TRIM](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/trim.html) that also, thus I would be inclined to use:

```
SELECT
    NULLIF(TRIM(fb.org_story),'') AS pvt_story
FROM prod.facebook AS fb
```

So, if you have NULLs and what them displayed as the text NULL we need to convert to TEXT then COALESCE,NVL,IFNULL the desired output

```
SELECT
    fb.org_story AS pvt_story
    ,fb.org_story::text AS as_text
    ,NVL(fb.org_story::text, 'NULL') as null_says_null_a
    ,COALESCE(fb.org_story::text, 'NULL') as null_says_null_b
    ,IFNULL(fb.org_story::text, 'NULL') as null_says_null_c
    ,IFF(fb.org_story IS NULL, 'NULL', fb.org_story::text ) as null_says_null_d
FROM VALUES (123), (null) AS fb(org_story)
```

| PVT_STORY | AS_TEXT | NULL_SAYS_NULL_A | NULL_SAYS_NULL_B | NULL_SAYS_NULL_C | NULL_SAYS_NULL_D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 123 | 123 | 123 | 123 | 123 |
|  |  | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Comment: org_story is an int. when I try this I see Numeric value '' is not recognized

Comment: @KristiLuna ah, that makes more sense, please see update

Answer (score 1):

you can use coalesce() as well

```
select coalesce(fb.org_story,'') AS pvt_story
FROM prod.facebook AS fb
```

Comment: org_story is an int.  when I try this I see Numeric value '' is not recognized

Answer (score 0):

Try One of these if you have Spaces in the data:

```sql
-- If you want to return `NULL` values
SELECT NULLIF(TRIM('      '), '')         + 1 AS "Test 1";  -- Returns NULL
SELECT NULLIF(TRIM(NULL), '')             + 2 AS "Test 2";  -- Returns NULL
SELECT NULLIF(TRIM(''), '')               + 3 AS "Test 3";  -- Returns NULL

-- If you want to return calculated values even if the field is null.
SELECT NVL(NULLIF(TRIM('      '), ''), 0) + 4 AS "Test 4";  -- Returns 4
SELECT NVL(NULLIF(TRIM(NULL), ''), 0)     + 5 AS "Test 5";  -- Returns 5
SELECT NVL(NULLIF(TRIM(''), ''), 0)       + 6 AS "Test 6";  -- Returns 6
```

### Example Usage:

```
SELECT NULLIF(TRIM(fb.org_story), '')             + 7 AS "pvt_story"
FROM prod.facebook AS fb;  -- Returns NULL


SELECT NVL(NULLIF(TRIM(fb.org_story), ''), 0)     + 8 AS "pvt_story"
FROM prod.facebook AS fb;  -- Returns 8
```